# compiling opencv with gpu cuda support

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu

I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 with CUDA 4.0.

I have installed the OpenCV 2.3.1 by CMAKE with WITH_CUDA flag on. And then I compiled the OpenCV solution in release and debug mode, but still when I used the `getCudaEnabledDevice` function of `CV::GPU` it is returning 0. This means it is not detecting the CUDA enabled device.

It seems that I have done everything right, still what is happening??

Can Anybody suggest where can be the problem now??.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But I have read in the willowgarage documents that opencv 2.3.1 supports cuda 4.0 only.opencv 2.4 supports cuda 4.1.

Comment: 2.3.1 definitly does not require 4.1, I doubt it will even work with it...

Is the cuda toolkit and sdk installed?
I highly recommend installing cmake-gui for easier installation, you might even see what cuda related stuff is not found (if applicable)
can you run device query using the toolkit? I do however recommend 2.4 w/ 4.1 seeing that it is available, I remember some supreme annoyances with regard to that specific version. but hey it's up to you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by
copying opencv_core243d.dll from `E:\opencv\build\gpu\x64\vc10\lib` folder to the work directory with the .exe.
Don't know why that should matter but it did.

Using cuda 5.0
  VS2010 express
win 7 x64