# Not able to detect CUDA enabled device in Opencv GPU

Tags: opencv, cuda, cmake, gpu, gpgpu

Hello,

I am trying to use Opencv GPU with CUDA.I ahve used the CMake for compiling the opencv 2.3.1 with cuda 4.0 But when I am trying to use the function cv::gpu:getCudaEnabledDevice() it returns me zero means no device available.

Though I have CUDA enabled gpu in my system.Anybody please help me with this I have tried a lot,In cmake it shows that no CUDA_SDK_ROOT_CIR not found.Which path should be given here?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613809/compiling-opencv-with-gpu-cuda-support?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You should update your NVIDIA Driver to latest from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.opencv 2.3.1 only supports cuda 4.0 and I have already downloaded the lates toolkit compatible with cuda 4.0.

Comment: OpenCV 2.4 supports toolkit 4.1 and 4.2. However CUDA is backward compatible, I think you just need to update your gpu driver.

Comment: Is OpenCv 2.4 full version available or it is only beta version??And does it matter that I should have latest version as I am using OpenCv 2.3.1 which is compatible with cuda 4.0. Also can you please tell me what does it mean by CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR and why opencv is not able to detect the cuda enabled device?

Comment: OpenCV 2.4 final version was released on 1st May 2012.
Download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/latest/download)

Comment: CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR is the path to the root directory of CUDA SDK installation.

Comment: means C:\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0(64bit) 
OR C:\NVIDIA Corporation 
OR C:\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0(64bit)\C
OR C:\
Which one of this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your cuda enabled gpu  is not indexed as device zero?  Also, try executing cuda SDK examples to check correct cuda setup.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the checklist:

1. Check your video propietary driver version
2. Check the binary you have compiled with ldd - are the libraries on place?
3. In CUDA samples compile and run deviceQuery - check the output
4. Use the device in dedicated mode, i.e. if you use X11, check the config that any reference to nvidia driver and so forth are completely wiped out from here.
5. Compile X11 and supplementary libraries from source, DO NOT obtain it from pre-compiled binary packages

This checklist covers 80% of CUDA mailfunctions for sure - checked it myself.